Copy/Paste not working in my Flutter app after adding the Localization
I added the flutter localization in my flutter app. Copy paste stopped working and it does not work even i copy text from somewhere else, it does not allow me to paste the text, please if someone have solution, let me know, thanks.

Try to explain more in details of your issue. What library is ? What have you tried to do ? The steps you've already made...

Have you addedd localizationsDelegates inside your MaterialApp ?
localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
],


yes i added these
     localizationsDelegates: [               AppLocalizations.delegate,               GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,               GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,               GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate             ],             locale: themeNotifier.currentLocale,             supportedLocales: [               Locale('en'),               Locale('ru'),               Locale('ar'),               Locale('fr'),               Locale('es'),             ],
